# OpenCV: how to access one contour in O(1) after call cvFindContours()?

Tags: opencv

I'm using OpenCV to compare two blobs in two images. Suppose I've known
a pair of blobs that are likely to be similar, and I know their indices 
in the contour arrays (generated by cvFindContours()), how can I get 
access to one contour in a constant time?

The most cumbersome way is to use the link operation (contours=contours->h_next) multiple times, but I wonder if there is a faster way to retrieve one contour in an array.

I use CV_RETR_EXTERNAL and CV_CHAIN_APPROX_NONE in calling cvFindContours().

Thanks!
-J.C.

Answer (score 2):

I think the function `cvGetSeqElem` does what you want. Quoting the [OpenCV docs](http://opencv.willowgarage.com/documentation/c/core_dynamic_structures.html?highlight=getseqelem#cvGetSeqElem): "The function has O(1) time complexity assuming that the number of blocks is much smaller than the number of elements." I suppose "blocks" means "contours" in this context.

Also, take a look at `cvCvtSeqToArray` ([link](http://opencv.willowgarage.com/documentation/c/core_dynamic_structures.html?highlight=cvcvtseqtoarray#cvCvtSeqToArray)), which copies a sequence to one continuous block of memory.

Comment: Thanks for the comments! I guess cvGetSeqElem is not what I want: it retrieves one element from a sequence -- in this case it's a point on a contour. I agree that cvCvtSeqToArray can do the job, but as you might notice, it is awkward to manipulate contours like this (new/delete, memory copy, etc...).